# How to withdraw contributions from Fidelity Roth IRA? Fidelity-specific

Tags: united-states, investing, roth-ira, contribution, fidelity

From my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong), contributions can be withdrawn from a Roth IRA at any time without any penalty. I opened a Roth IRA with Fidelity two weeks ago and contributed $3,000 for the year of 2021. I'm still learning about how the Fidelity interface (pc) works. So far it says that my "Total account value" and "Settled Cash" is $3,000 but "Available to withdraw" is $0.00 and I'm wondering why that is.

Basically what I want to know is would I be able to pull my contribution out if I need to and what specifically would I need to do for that. Would I just transfer it back to the account I used to get the cash in?

Comment: Did you invest the $3000 in something like a mutual fund? That would explain why your "available to withdraw" is at $0. If so, if you want to withdraw your contributions (which should only be done as a last resort), you would have to sell that investment first.

Comment: No I haven't invested it into anything it's just sitting there. I'm assuming because it has to "clear," it said something about that in the withdrawal section but Fidelity hasn't given me any indication about that or how long it would take if that is the case.

Comment: Have you tried calling them?

Comment: Odd that it would say $3000 settled cash then. Settled cash is generally equivalent to available to withdraw.